# Checking even or odd `1` bits in a number

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit, logical-operators

I want to check if number has all even or odd bits set to one and only them. For eg.:

Number `42` is correct, because in a binary code `101010` it has all and only even bits sets to `1`.
Number `21` is also correct, `10101`.

Number `69` for eg. `1000101` is not correct, because there are only three odd bits sets to `1`.

I've tried using different operations with `^, &, >>, <<` and i still have no idea how can i do this using these operators. Yes, i need to do this using logical operators in `C`.

Comment: To tell if a number is odd or even, you only need to check the *last* bit.

Comment: What purpose do you get for doing this?

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Comment: This question has been asked [many times] before ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those numbers have that property that `(x ^ (x >> 1)) + 1` is a power of 2. And `y` is a power of 2 if `y & (y - 1) == 0`

So one test could be `((x ^ (x >> 1)) + 1) & (x ^ (x >> 1)) == 0` which would work for numbers of any size.

Comment: that's great, but storing `(x ^ (x >> 1))` in a seperate variable y is better since the program won't need to recalculate the value of that expression anymore

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned uu;

    for (uu=0; uu < 43; uu++ ) {
        int res;
        res = (((uu & 0xAAAAAAAA) == uu) || ((uu & 0x55555555) == uu) );
        printf("%u: %d\n", uu, res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If people start commenting on (or correcting) the whitespace, the non-whitespace must be correct ;-)

Comment: 0 could be considered a corner case, since it has no bits set at all. (but it least it does not have the *wrong* bits set ;-) Depending on the requerements, you could of course exclude zero separately.

Comment: This returns "true" for 69, which was supposed to not be correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isEven(int n){
   bool isEven = true;
   while(n){
      if( n & 1 ){
          isEven = !isEven;
      }
      n = n >> 1;
   }

   return isEven;
}
```

while(n) will continue as long as n is != 0, that is still has one's in it.
if the first bit is one then we change the even parameter to the opposite (even turns to odd and vice versa), on each iteration we shift the number one bit to the right.

Comment: Posting the code does not help, please explain in 1 or 2 lines.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked. This checks if the number has even or odd number of bits set. The question was to check of ALL odd numbered bits were set, or if ALL evened numbered bits were set.

Comment: I dont need to check if number is even. I want to check if all even bits of number are equals to 1 and all odd bits equals to 0. Second situation is symmetrical.